# OpenCL/GL interop: write_imagef to shared gltexture is all white (1,1,1,1)

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, interop, opencl

I'm trying to write a ray tracer using OpenCL. I have, however, run into a bit of trouble.

I want to share texture memory between OpenGL and OpenCL to avoid unnecessary memory copying back and forth. My program runs fine, I check after each call to GL and CL, and I get no errors whatsoever.

As explained in the title, writing to the texture in the kernel using write_imagef results in 1.0 in every channel.

I suspect there is something wrong with the format of the texture, but I have been looking all over the internet for valid texture formats, and I can't see what could be wrong. I have tried different combinations of write_imageui and write_imagef and texture formats with no luck.

Kernel Program:

```
__kernel void Draw( __global __write_only image2d_t image, const int width, const int height )
{
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);
    // Write some red color
    write_imagef(image, (int2)(x,y), (float4)(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f));
}
```

I have confirmed that my kernel is running at all by modifying my code to

```
if(x < width/2)
    write_imagef(image, (int2)(x,y), (float4)(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f));
```

and initialising my texture to a colour (green). The result: a half white and half green texture, meaning that the kernel is writing to the image *where* it is supposed to (but not the correct values).

Creation of my texture and creation of cl_mem object:

```
// Create OpenGL Texture
GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures( 1, &textureID );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, imageWidth, imageHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, nullptr );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

// Create OpenCL memobject from gl texture
cl_mem textureMem = clCreateFromGLTexture2D( context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, textureID, &ret );
```

Executing the kernel and rendering the texture:

```
// Main loop
...

// Set kernel args
ret = clSetKernelArg( kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&textureMem );
ret = clSetKernelArg( kernel, 1, sizeof(int), (void *)&imageWidth );
ret = clSetKernelArg( kernel, 2, sizeof(int), (void *)&imageHeight );

cl_event event[3];
// Aquire texture
ret = clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects( commandQueue, 1, &textureMem, 0, NULL, &event[0] );

// Execute kernel
size_t globalWorkSize[] = {imageWidth, imageHeight};
size_t localWorkSize[] = {32,32};
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( commandQueue, kernel, 2, NULL, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 1, &event[0], &event[1] );

// Release texture
ret = clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects( commandQueue, 1, &textureMem, 1, &event[1], &event[2] );

clWaitForEvents( 1, &event[2] );

// Render textured quad with OpenGL
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
glUseProgram( quadProgramID );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer );
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glUseProgram(0);
glfwSwapBuffers( window );
glFinish();
```

I could also add that I have successfully been able to send and process regular float arrays in the kernel using the same host program.

I was hoping someone had similar a problem, and as I'm completely stuck right now I might as well just throw this question out there.

And if the code above isn't relevant enough, here is the full source http://pastebin.com/LhBhQDSR

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is your commandQueue in-order or out-of-order?  How are you rendering the image?

Comment: The command queue is in-order. I added the bit of code that draws the textured quad to the screen above.

Comment: Then it must be a "channel-order" issue. How did you create the image object? Which channel order? Maybe it is not CL_RGBA ? I mean that image2dt object in the host code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with the channel format. I changed the internal format when creating the glTexture from GL_RGBA to GL_RGBA32F and it now works like a charm.